# LocaleCompare sort strings with special characters differently for IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have issue with localeCompare, when compare strings containing special characters.
I noticed that IE browsers sorts strings with those characters different than Firefox and Chrome.

For example the output of the following code:

```
var collator = new Intl.Collator('en-US', { 
     caseFirst: 'lower', 
     ignorePunctuation: false, 
     numeric: true});

var myArray = [' ','_','-',',','!','.','(',')','[',']','{','}','@','&','#','%','^','+','$'];
console.log(myArray.sort(collator.compare));
```

will return

```
 // IE
 ["-", " ", "!", "#", "$", "%", "&", "(", ")", ",", ".", "@", "[", "]", "^", "_", "{", "}", "+"] 
 // Chrome
 [" ", "_", "-", ",", "!", ".", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", "@", "&", "#", "%", "^", "+", "$"]
```

Is there a way to solve that and make both browsers work the same?

Or may be there is a way to pass ordering schema to the localeCompare and define the custom order of special characters?